# Determining $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{n-1} \sqrt{x}\, dx}{n^{3/2}}$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{n-1} \sqrt{x} \,dx}{n^{3/2}}$$

Can someone please provide the step by step solution to this? I somehow can't get a grasp of limits.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: I suggest going forward that you use comments to ask questions in regards to solutions posted on your behalf, rather than open a new question.  It benefits others who might have the same question to have things in one place and self contained.  ;-))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

$$\int_0^{n-1}\sqrt{x}\,dx=\frac23 (n-1)^{3/2}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{n^{3/2}}\int_0^{n-1}\sqrt{x}\,dx&=\frac23\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{3/2}\\\\
&=\frac23\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{3/2}\\\\
&=\frac23
\end{align}$$